# c++ gethostbyaddr with user input

Tags: c++, network-programming

I am writing c++ code for a telnet client. I am having problems getting the host address from the user input.

```
struct in_addr peers;

cin>>peers;

peerserver = gethostbyaddr((const char*)peers,4,AF_INET);

if (peerserver == NULL)
    exit(0);
```

I am new to c++, can anyone suggest a better way of getting the host addr with user input. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `gethostbyname`, not `gethostbyaddr`. `gethostbyaddr` assumes that you've already got the IP address.

```
char peers[256];
cin >> peers;
struct hostent *ent = gethostbyname(peers);
printf("%04x\n", *(int *)(ent->h_addr));
```

Comment: Better yet, use an `std::string` and getaddrinfo (http://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo)

Comment: ... and not forgetting that `getaddrinfo` (and now mostly obsolete `gethostby*` functions) may return several addresses/entries. Relation `name <-> address` is many to many.